# how to handle when phone switch off in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to get the time when an iPhone switches off due to battery or other reasons. But, I need to save when the phone switches off time and when the phone switches on time using objective-c code. How do I do this?

Comment: It is not possible to get programmatically the iPhone switch off and on time.

Comment: You can not get time it is OS related operation and Apple will not allow you to access such kind of operations

Comment: But , i need that is our requirement. if u have any another suggestion tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect phone switch off. But what you can do is to add an observer via Notification Center to monitor battery level changes.

```
UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification
```

You need to create a logic to check current battery level and then save the time stamp.

Comment: I know if background task service like location is ON, we can get the battery level changes if app is in background, but can we get the battery level changes if app is in killed/terminated state?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot receive such notifications when your app is suspended. But I think there is away to achieve what you want by using remote notifications...what you can do is send a remote notification to the app and in the handling of remote notifications detect battery levels and save the time stamp. It's not pretty but I think it's the only way

Comment: that means i will use push notifications for that?

Comment: Yes...I mean this is by no means a solution...but it's kind of a hack